# Sybase ASE identify columns of keys of multiple tables

Tags: database, sap-ase

I'm trying to identify the columns making up keys in ASE.

Sybase has the solution listed here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.help.ase.15.5/title.htm

I have a slightly modified version below, however it only works (just as sybase's solution) if I look up for a single table, but I want to use the 'in' keyword and look up all the tables in one shot.

Could I get some help, as to why the solution below does not work? It only generates the list of columns for 't5' table.

```
declare @keycnt integer
declare @objname varchar(256)
select @keycnt = keycnt, @objname = sysobjects.name from sysindexes, sysobjects
     where 
     --sysobjects.id = object_id("t5")
     --sysobjects.id = object_id("t4")
     sysobjects.id in (object_id("t5"), object_id("t4"))
     and sysobjects.id = sysindexes.id
     and indid = 1
while @keycnt > 0
begin
     select index_col(@objname, 1, @keycnt)
     select @keycnt = @keycnt - 1
end
```

These are the tables I'm using for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE t4(
    [value] [varchar] (500) not NULL ,
  CONSTRAINT pk_g4 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    [value]
  )
)

CREATE TABLE t5(
    [myvalue] [varchar] (500) not NULL ,
  CONSTRAINT pk_g4 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    [myvalue]
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:

**Using OR**

```
declare @keycnt integer
declare @objname varchar(256)
select @keycnt = keycnt, @objname = sysobjects.name from sysindexes, sysobjects
     where 
     --sysobjects.id = object_id("t5")
     --sysobjects.id = object_id("t4")
     (sysobjects.id = object_id("t5") OR sysobjects.id = object_id("t4"))
     and sysobjects.id = sysindexes.id
     and indid = 1
while @keycnt > 0
begin
     select index_col(@objname, 1, @keycnt)
     select @keycnt = @keycnt - 1
end
```

**Or Using Dynamic SQL to properly use the IN.**